# Possible causes in error with SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild & TFS 2015

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, tfsbuild, sonar-runner

I have setup TFS 2015 update 3, with several projects. each one of them has its own build definitions, moreover some of those build definition include SonarQube for MS Build tasks (begin-end). so far I setup 1 build agent in other machine to work as a build server, and SonarQube 5.6 instance.

I have been struggling for two days how to solve this issue that appears **only in one** of the build definitions:

```
2016-10-11T18:29:54.0515420Z Generating SonarQube project properties file to c:\_work\4\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
2016-10-11T18:29:54.0525412Z ##[error]The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
2016-10-11T18:29:54.0525412Z ##[error]Possible causes:
2016-10-11T18:29:54.0535414Z ##[error]1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
2016-10-11T18:29:54.0535414Z ##[error]2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 12.0 upwards are supported
2016-10-11T18:29:54.0545417Z ##[error]3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
```

checking this error, I analyzed possible causes:

1. My build definitions has the begin - end tasks, so this should not be the issue
2. Currently the build server is using MSBUILD 14, therefore this is not the problem
3. The task run by the build agent, I really hope it calls the task from the same directory.

Either way I tried to reproduce the behavior, I logged into the server and tried to make the same calls that build agent perform and I got the same result in the server, but again, this happens just with one of the projects, the other one keeps working perfectly.

I delete the .sonar folder as well as the .sonarqube folder, it keeps giving me that error.

**EDIT***

this is the build definition:

```
{
  "build": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Fetch the Quality Profile from SonarQube",
      "task": {
        "id": "eae5b2cc-ac5e-4cba-b022-a06621f9c01f",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "projectKey": "PROJECT1",
        "projectName": "PROJECT1",
        "projectVersion": "1.0",
        "connectedServiceName": "ab3a4128-62ca-4e35-88f0-a2c6aae2a123",
        "dbUrl": "",
        "dbUsername": "",
        "dbPassword": "",
        "cmdLineArgs": "/d:sonar.verbose=true",
        "configFile": "",
        "breakBuild": "false"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Build solution $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\\XXXX\\Build.proj",
      "task": {
        "id": "c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "solution": "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\\XXXX\\Build.proj",
        "platform": "$(BuildPlatform)",
        "configuration": "$(BuildConfiguration)",
        "msbuildArguments": "/p:BuildingInsideVisualStudio=true;FullBuild=true",
        "clean": "false",
        "restoreNugetPackages": "false",
        "logProjectEvents": "false",
        "msbuildLocationMethod": "version",
        "msbuildVersion": "14.0",
        "msbuildArchitecture": "x86",
        "msbuildLocation": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": true,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Test Assemblies $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\\Droplocation\\**\\XXXX*test*.dll",
      "task": {
        "id": "ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "testAssembly": "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\\Droplocation\\**\\XXXX*test*.dll",
        "testFiltercriteria": "",
        "runSettingsFile": "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\\Environment\\Test.runsettings",
        "overrideTestrunParameters": "",
        "codeCoverageEnabled": "true",
        "runInParallel": "false",
        "vsTestVersion": "latest",
        "pathtoCustomTestAdapters": "",
        "otherConsoleOptions": "",
        "testRunTitle": "",
        "platform": "$(BuildPlatform)",
        "configuration": "$(BuildConfiguration)",
        "publishRunAttachments": "true"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Finish the analysis and upload the results to SonarQube",
      "task": {
        "id": "730d8de1-7a4f-424c-9542-fe7cc02604eb",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {}
    },
    {
      "enabled": false,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Publish Artifact: $(BuildConfiguration)",
      "task": {
        "id": "1d341bb0-2106-458c-8422-d00bcea6512a",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "CopyRoot": "droplocation\\Build\\$(BuildPlatform)\\$(BuildConfiguration)",
        "Contents": "**\\*",
        "ArtifactName": "$(BuildConfiguration)",
        "ArtifactType": "FilePath",
        "TargetPath": "\\\\SERVER0009\\PROJECT1\\Dev\\FT1\\Droplocation\\Build\\$(BuildPlatform)"
      }
    }
  ],
  "options": [
    {
      "enabled": false,
      "definition": {
        "id": "7c555368-ca64-4199-add6-9ebaf0b0137d"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "multipliers": "[]",
        "parallel": "false",
        "continueOnError": "true",
        "additionalFields": "{}"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": false,
      "definition": {
        "id": "a9db38f9-9fdc-478c-b0f9-464221e58316"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "workItemType": "61",
        "assignToRequestor": "true",
        "additionalFields": "{}"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": false,
      "definition": {
        "id": "57578776-4c22-4526-aeb0-86b6da17ee9c"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "additionalFields": "{}"
      }
    }
  ],
  "triggers": [
    {
      "schedules": [
        {
          "branchFilters": [
            "+$/PROJECT1"
          ],
          "timeZoneId": "SA Pacific Standard Time",
          "startHours": 2,
          "startMinutes": 0,
          "daysToBuild": 31,
          "scheduleJobId": "d4f0f8c0-00c1-433a-af52-9e1b9e5c3b0c"
        }
      ],
      "triggerType": 8
    }
  ],
  "variables": {
    "BuildPlatform": {
      "value": "AnyCPU"
    },
    "BuildConfiguration": {
      "value": "Debug"
    },
    "system.debug": {
      "value": "true"
    }
  },
  "demands": [
    "gulp",
    "server"
  ],
  "retentionRules": [
    {
      "branches": [
        "+refs/heads/*"
      ],
      "artifacts": [
        "build.SourceLabel"
      ],
      "daysToKeep": 10,
      "minimumToKeep": 1,
      "deleteBuildRecord": true,
      "deleteTestResults": true
    }
  ],
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://SERVERexptfs1:8080/tfs/DevOpsCollection/82853fb4-72eb-4847-8fe3-405d951fdc67/_apis/build/Definitions/6"
    },
    "web": {
      "href": "http://SERVERexptfs1:8080/tfs/_permalink/_build/index?collectionId=498d3af0-ad32-4e5c-9870-7b5ad0346571&projectId=82853fb4-72eb-4847-8fe3-405d951fdc67&definitionId=6"
    }
  },
  "jobAuthorizationScope": 1,
  "jobTimeoutInMinutes": 60,
  "repository": {
    "properties": {
      "labelSources": "0",
      "tfvcMapping": "{\"mappings\":[{\"serverPath\":\"$/PROJECT1/Dev/FT1\",\"mappingType\":\"map\",\"localPath\":\"\\\\\"},{\"serverPath\":\"$/PROJECT1/Dev/FT1/Workspaces\",\"mappingType\":\"cloak\",\"localPath\":\"\\\\Workspaces\"},{\"serverPath\":\"$/PROJECT1/Dev/FT1/Documentation\",\"mappingType\":\"cloak\",\"localPath\":\"\\\\Documentation\"}]}"
    },
    "id": "$/",
    "type": "TfsVersionControl",
    "name": "PROJECT1",
    "url": "http://SERVERexptfs1:8080/tfs/DevOpsCollection/",
    "defaultBranch": "$/PROJECT1/Dev/FT1",
    "rootFolder": "$/PROJECT1",
    "clean": "false",
    "checkoutSubmodules": false
  },
  "quality": 1,
  "authoredBy": {
    "id": "70764a8f-5a60-4969-a13b-771c30beaae8",
    "displayName": "Cristian Galindo Londono",
    "uniqueName": "XXXXINSPECTION\\CGLondono",
    "url": "http://SERVERexptfs1:8080/tfs/DevOpsCollection/_apis/Identities/70764a8f-5a60-4969-a13b-771c30beaae8",
    "imageUrl": "http://SERVERexptfs1:8080/tfs/DevOpsCollection/_api/_common/identityImage?id=70764a8f-5a60-4969-a13b-771c30beaae8"
  },
  "queue": {
    "pool": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Default"
    },
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Default"
  },
  "uri": "vstfs:///Build/Definition/6",
  "type": 2,
  "revision": 39,
  "createdDate": "2016-10-13T13:56:02.600Z",
  "id": 6,
  "name": "FT1.Build.Sonar",
  "url": "http://SERVERexptfs1:8080/tfs/DevOpsCollection/82853fb4-72eb-4847-8fe3-405d951fdc67/_apis/build/Definitions/6",
  "project": {
    "id": "82853fb4-72eb-4847-8fe3-405d951fdc67",
    "name": "PROJECT1",
    "url": "http://SERVERexptfs1:8080/tfs/DevOpsCollection/_apis/projects/82853fb4-72eb-4847-8fe3-405d951fdc67",
    "state": "wellFormed",
    "revision": 31
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share with us a repro of the issue? It seems that the end step can't find the .sonarqube/out folder, or that folder doesn't contain any relevant information (ProjectInfo.xml files). What kind of projects are there in your solution?

Comment: Since the issue only occurs in one build definition, the issue should be not related to TFS  environment. Could you let us know what kind of project are you using in this build definition? According to this site http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild, analysis of BizTalk, SharePoint, ASP.NET vNext projects, and Web Site Solutions is not supported.

Comment: It is a set of c# library projects. As a matter of fact, in the folder **.sonarqube/out** folder there  is no information related to the projects. I am at investigation mode, due this build definition was working, trying to figure what change and affect its proper working

Comment: I create a powershell script that executes the process, and it works fine, Why TFS task continues failing??? Grrrrr

Comment: Could you share detailed build definition settings and a test project?

Comment: Does it works if you update other build definition to build this project?

Comment: I already create two more build definitions, same behavior happens, today I will teardown the process in order to solve this haunting build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging, some sacrifices and many curses I found that targets used by the SonarQube runner for MSBuild were skipped.

One of the targets (SonarQubeImportBeforeInfo) has the condition `BuildingInsideVisualStudio != 'true'` . I was using the SAME variable for another inner target (Coincidence)